Precompiled spdlog - included header file not found
I try to use precompiled spdlog (with external fmt library) with my project.  Currently I'm working on Windows 10, using MSYS2 with GCC for development.
I've performed the following steps:
git clone https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
cd spdlog && mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL=ON .. && ninja

Then I've copied the resulting files in /build folder to MY_PROJECT/spdlog_precompiled folder and spdlog's /include folder to MY_PROJECT folder (that /include folder has, a.o., spdlog/fmt/fmt.h file)
I've added the following lines to my project's CMakeLists.txt (NAME holds target's name):
set(spdlog_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/spdlog_precompiled)
find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(
  ${NAME}
  spdlog::spdlog $<$<BOOL:${MINGW}>:ws2_32>)

target_include_directories(${NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

However, when I try to build my project, I get the following errors:
C:/Development/Spirallo/WinCanSpiralloComponent/src/spirallolib/DebugLog.hpp:10:10: fatal error: spdlog/fmt/fmt.h: No such file or directory
   10 | #include "spdlog/fmt/fmt.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Even when I add include_directories(include) in top-level CMakeLists.txt, the error persists.
What am I doing wrong?

"Then I've copied the resulting files in /build folder to ..." - This is not how a project is prepared to the distribution. Instead, perform the project's installation (ninja install). Before that you may want to modify CMAKE_INSTALL_REFIX variable for choose custom directory as install prefix. E.g. cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/MY_PROJECT/spdlog_precompiled

That did the trick. Just to clarify - I had to perform ninja install on the library, not the project.
